# Laravel 5.6 email validator fails on valid email address

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.6

I am testing the security of my app and I have the following issue, when I type in the following email address into my email field at login and try to validate it with Laravel 5.6 built in email validator.

11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111thebestemail@yahoo.com

It fails and gives me the error of "The email must be a valid email address."

Well, this is clearly a valid email address in theory and it should not fail and this is a serious issue.

What should I do to avoid this mistake with similar email addresses?

Any ideas are welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel is, in fact, correct in indicating that this email address is invalid. The "username" part (before the `@` symbol) has a maximum of 64 characters. The one you have is 110 characters long.

See section 4.5.3.1 of [RFC 2821](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt).

Comment: Thanks @Mike, that is just what I have been looking for!

Comment: On an internals level, Laravel's using PHP's `filter_var('foo@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);` for this.